# VS Code error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json'"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

I get this ENOENT error on Terminal. I tried some of the solutions available but I'm still not able to run either app.

I ran `code --verbose`.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ raul_fdz$ code --verbose
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:54.846Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>),/Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>)
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.126Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.127Z] from: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.128Z] args: {
  _: [],
  diff: false,
  merge: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  'pre-release': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'ms-enable-electron-run-as-node': false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  'enable-smoke-test-driver': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-keytar': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': 'a0c1cb1d-20f1-4880-b7c0-43c3db315015',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  '__enable-file-policy': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  'disable-dev-shm-usage': false,
  logsPath: '/Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/20220815T224454'
}
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.136Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.139Z] Resolved machine identifier: b617f940faadfdad2ff8b88a9a23748bbcc4c489bc07b6269fb8f61ac7316c3c
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.145Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.175Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json'
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.188Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/User'
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.206Z] StorageMainService: creating application storage
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.235Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.238Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.238Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    backupPath: '/Users/raul_fdz/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups/1660617796867',
    remoteAuthority: undefined
  }
]
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.240Z] windowsManager#doOpenEmpty {
  restore: true,
  remoteAuthority: undefined,
  filesToOpen: undefined,
  forceNewWindow: true
}
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.242Z] IPC Object URL: Registered new channel vscode:7c0b4b2f-9852-4284-ac7f-1ade9416a62f.
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.243Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 1 display(s) { mode: 1, x: 128, y: 23, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.244Z] window#validateWindowState: 1 monitor working area { x: 0, y: 23, width: 1280, height: 777 }
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.245Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 1, x: 128, y: 23, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.464Z] window#load: attempt to load window (id: 1)
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.584Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 0, emptyToRestore: 1, emptyToOpen: 0)
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.584Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.601Z] update#setState idle
[main 2022-08-16T03:44:55.608Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[main 2022-08-16T03:45:16.037Z] CodeWindow: detected unresponsive
[main 2022-08-16T03:45:25.607Z] update#checkForUpdates, state =  idle
[main 2022-08-16T03:45:25.607Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2022-08-16T03:45:26.158Z] update#setState idle
```

The window is not responding.

MacBookPro 5,5 running dosdude1's patch Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: what if you run with `--no-sandbox`? what if you run with `--disable-gpu`? (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146669)). related [google search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+vscode+issues+%22ENOENT%3A+no+such+file+or+directory%2C+stat%22+%22Library%2FApplication+Support%2FCode%2FUser%2Fsettings.json%22)